# UrlHelper.Action generate Url without controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to generate Url without controller name. If I use code below...

```
 @Url.Action("d", null, new { id = Model.DownloadId })
```

...I get url like this

```
http://localhost:814/DefaultController/d/11234
```

I would like to get url like this

```
http://localhost:814/d/11234
```

My route code..

```
routes.MapRoute("Download result form", "d/{id}", new { controller = "Result", action = "DownloadForm" });
```

... handles url like above(only with Action and Id without Controller name) perfectly.

Comment: MVC assumes that default controller is the root of your site.  You can either create a custom route that defines hostname no controller as your default route, or you could simply create the href your self: href='/d/@Model.DownloadId'

Comment: The default controller is described in route, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your first suggestion, also creating url by myself seems a little odd in MVC world. It should be soem kind of solution to create URL using MVC helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would cause you trouble in that these actions would conflict with binding to other controllers.

To make clean urls like what you want it would be more usual to omit the action name, e.g. this page  `stackoverflow/questions/{id}`

UPDATE

provide the Controller in the Action to allow it to know which route to pick, i.e.

```
 @Url.Action("DownloadForm", "Result", new { id = Model.DownloadId })
```

If that doesn't work it is being grabbed by another route, so the ordering of your routes is not as you want them.

Comment: Agreed.  I had assumed the OP was trying to like to resources that are outside of any controller.

Comment: I have updated my post. It won't because I have custom route, please check my updated answer.